# What does the red exclamation mark next to English (language dropdown) mean in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm getting the generic "There are one or more errors on the page" error when I try to update the build number for the pre-release version of my app.  I have done an exhaustive review of every tab, localization, setting, and form factor and I can only find one item marked as problematic.

On the Versions tab I see this for my *currently-shipping* version of the app:

[image]

When I open the dropdown and scroll to the bottom, I see this:

[image]

I can't find anything else marked as a problem, and when I select the red exclamation mark in the drop down, the page reloads, but nothing changes and nothing is obviously broken.

I also note that on the *pre-release version* of my app, I have a blank entry in the localization list:
[image]

Attempts to remove the blank line reveal it to be Flemish.  It also solves the problem—I can save the changes after I remove it. However, once I click save, leave iTunes Connect, and return, the build number has reverted and Ghost Flemish has returned, and so has the error.

(Per other questions / answers I did make sure the price is set and all fields have been filled out correctly.)

Comment: Same problem here... Just spoke with Apple Support > working on it...

Comment: Good to know... was it Flemish?

Comment: Yes... Dutch went away and a ghost Flemish entry was created, giving errors when trying to submit a new version

Comment: @i_am_jorf Ask to apple with snapshot. It may be temporary issue. apple developers also searching on SO

Comment: Apple has confirmed with us there is nothing to be done except contact them and have their engineers manually fix it.  Leaving this question undeleted as a support group for other people banging their heads on their desks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has confirmed this is a bug with iTunes Connect and you have to contact developer support to get it resolved.  I have successfully done this.

Comment: how much time did apple take?

Answer (score 16):

With the new capability to have just one set of screenshots, go to where you add screenshots and click on Media Manager. Once there, for all the other iPhone sizes, check the "Use 5.5-Inch Display".

Comment: Only this worked for me. Had to check similar settings for tablet size